# Require a field to be filled out before a record tab is closed

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-record-page

On my chat transcript lightning record page, I have a LWC component added that is a lightning-record-edit-form. This form contains two custom fields for the user to quickly and easily fill out. The business would like the disposition__c field to be filled out before the user exits out of the record page. Any ideas on the best way to do this? The highlighted field in the image below is the field we want to be required. I know I can make the field required in the LWC itself, but we want the user to be prompted to fill it out every time. The user could end the session and close out of the tab before filling out the form, which is what we don't want happening. In this case, we would want a pop up message to show to let the user know that they need to fill out the field.

I have also played with validation rules, however once a user ends the session they would simply leave the page and not make any other changes, thus never triggering the validation rule.

If I make the field required on the field level, the messaging session never gets created in the first place.

[image]